# Changing gstreamer pipeline to opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, ip-camera, hikvision

I have successfully installed and built gstreamer on opencv. It says YES when i print(cv2.getBuildInformation()).

```
Gstreamer version: 1.14.0
opencv version: 3.4.5.20
```

Bumped into a wall for quite a while at the moment, was using the gstreamer pipeline. It works wonderfully.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.65:554/Streaming/Channels/400 uridecodebin0::source::latency=10
```

This is the python script I've written for the gstreamer pipeline.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

pipe = '"rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.65:554/Streaming/Channels/400" latency=10 ! appsink'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pipe)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('VideoCapture not opened')
    exit(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print('empty frame')
        break

    cv2.imshow('display', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I keep getting this error though, unable to troubleshoot what caused this.

```
gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Found the answer by Fixing the pipeline using rtspsrc instead of playbin.

Opencv's VideoCapture is not able to take `autovideoconvert` and `autovideosink`. A work around would be to use `videoconvert` and `appsink` when using rtspsrc but latency can't be adjusted. However, if you want to adjust the latency you will need to use decodebin to decode instead of avdec_h264

e.g. `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location://admin:password@192.168.1.65:554 latency=20 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink`

NB: Pipeline will work in the python script but may not work in the command line.

This is for RTSP with IP cameras!

Cheers.